# Ember.js and jsfiddle problems

Tags: ember.js, jsfiddle

I'm new to the javascript world, so don't hesitate to point out the obvious.
I was trying to create a jsfiddle to ask a question on how to insert some content in the div element created by the App.Column view.

However I failed to get the fiddle to work, anyone who can point out why my errors?

The console logs this: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'extend' of undefined

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Aqrrj/2/

The JQueryUI-widget is taken from https://github.com/lukemelia/jquery-ui-ember and there is also a working example which I started from.

cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 2 problems:

By creating an application and assigning it to `var App = Ember.Application.create()` your are not making it available on the global object. Removing the `var` makes `App` global and therefore usable in your Handlebars template.

Second you are referring to a view class `App.Column` but it is never declared in your JavaScript code.

So your example can be fixed by the following lines, see http://jsfiddle.net/pangratz666/pSKgV/:

```js
App = Ember.Application.create();
...
App.Column = Ember.View.extend();
```

Comment: many thanks! it was the 'var' that got me. I deleted my column view when trying to debug my code and forgot to put it back in before posting. You will get my up vote when I have the reputation to do so.